# Capability based security in Windows 8/Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-8, sandbox

I want to evaluate the new sandboxing mechanism in Windows 8/Windows Server 2012. I searched MSDN site for any resources but the documentation is extremely scarce. In comparison with FreeBSD Capsicum documentation, the one provided by Microsoft is just unusable.

How are we supposed to build robust sandboxed apps? Are the sandboxing APIs intended for metro style apps only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "sandboxing APIs".  All "metro" (Windows 8 UI Applications) are sandboxed.  I'm not aware of any way to sandbox desktop applications in the same way. See [here](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/17/3026590/microsoft-windows-8-developers-windows-store-sandboxing).

> Metro apps are pretty tightly sandboxed, and apps submitted to the
>   Windows Store need to declare many types of capabilities that they use
>   — not unlike Google Play's permissions list.
>
> . . .
>
> Windows 8 features a specific SDK for Metro style apps . . .

Comment: I mean an API similar to FreeBSD Capsicum (that's why I mentioned it in my question). Think for CAS in the native/C++ world, not in .NET world (not the best analogy though). In my case I work on a desktop C++ project. Is it possible to have the same (or similar) capability based security model as the one used for metro style apps? The biggest problem I have is the scarce, unclear and sometimes the contradicting documentation on MSDN.

Comment: That's what the second quote was about.  The capability based security is build-in to the SDK for metro.  I'm going to guess that the confusing part of the documentation is where it refers to "Windows 8 UI applications".  This specifically refers to (formerly) "metro" apps.

Comment: I see it now. Well, all that story with name/brand (metro, Windows 8 UI, Modern UI, etc.) changing was one of the things that confused me. Another thing that confuses me is the scarce documentation, but I guess this is because Windows 8 is not officially released yet. I guess MSF will add more content to MSDN once Windows 8 is shipped.

Answer (score 1):

A quick explanation of capabilities: There are certain potentially sensitive things that you can do on a user's machine, such as access the Pictures library or use the webcam.  If an app wants to do these things, the developer must declare a capability in the app's manifest.  Then, when users download the app from the Windows Store, they can clearly see if the app is using any of this functionality.  More info and a list of all of the capabilities is provided at [App capability declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx).

Regarding sandboxing, there is some information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673561(v=vs.85).aspx.  Yes, Metro-style apps are sandboxed in a way that desktop apps are not.

There is a whitepaper discussing security in Windows Store apps built with HTML5 at [Secure development of Metro style apps with HTML5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27408).  There are also some [common security scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464946.aspx) documented.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've already read all these links and they don't answer my question. First, I have to say that I am experienced with the capability based security model. I've done two large projects with FreeBSD Capsicum and that's why I mentioned it in my question. Right now, I work on desktop C++ project and I want to know if there is a way to use capability based security model. For example, what is the analogue of cap_enter() function from Capsicum (if any)? As a feedback, I think the documentation is highly unstructured and MSF failed to send a message as a whole.